# Export google doc as PDF and send with Nodemailer as attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, nodemailer

So, keep banging by stupid head against the wall. Trying to create a Firebase function to extract a google doc as PDF using the drive API (v.3) and then attaching the extracted file to an email sendt with Nodemailer.

I do not get any error messages, and the email sends successfully with a PDF attachment. The problem is that the file is corrupted, and cannot be viewed.

**Updated**

Here is the full code for exporting the doc, sending the email and setting up the Firebase function. I have excluded any try - catch and error handling for simplicity. The email will produce a perfectly usable attachment if I try with a .txt file; like `new Buffer.from('Test string', 'utf8').`

```
const jwtClient = asUserEmail =>
  new google.auth.JWT(
    serviceAccount.client_email,
    undefined,
    serviceAccount.private_key,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    asUserEmail,
  );

const initializeDrive = asUserEmail =>
  google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth: jwtClient(asUserEmail),
  });

const exportAsPDF = async (fileId, asUserEmail) => {
  const drive = initializeDrive(asUserEmail);
  const result = await drive.files.export(
    {
      fileId: fileId,
      mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    },
    {
      responseType: 'arrayBuffer',
    },
  );
  return result.data;
};

const sendMail = async arrayBuffer => {
  const to = 'their@mail.com';
  const from = '"Your name here" <your@mail.com>';
  const template = `Test`;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      type: 'OAuth2',
      user: 'user@email.com',
      serviceClient: serviceAccount.client_id,
      privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key,
    },
  });

  await transporter.verify();

  await transporter.sendMail({
    from: from,
    to: to,
    subject: 'Test ✔',
    html: template,
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: 'test.pdf',
        content: new Buffer.from(arrayBuffer),
        contentType: 'application/pdf',
      },
    ],
  });
};

exports.emailAsPDF = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    // Check for auth state
  }

  const fileId = 'google-drive-file-id';
  const asUserEmail = context.auth.token.email;
  const extractedArrayBuffer = await exportAsPDF(fileId, asUserEmail);
  await sendMail(extractedArrayBuffer);
});
```

Suspect there is a mismatch between what the drive extract method provides and what I should provide as attachment.

The extracted arrayBuffer from the Drive API looks something like this:

stream\n' +
     'x��Q�JC1\f}�W�YX��Iӂ\b*n��\u0005?@�`0���`n�\n' +
     '\u0016�\u0006JnN�97)\u0001z�ȯ"\t���-�\u0015��\u000b\u001c�\u001a)�^��\u0005�:\u0016M1s5n��_N&��a\u000bKrڇ�6���iZ\u0015 �4���]�\u001fk%d�M8{.�{�La��\u0016�Y��\u0002�.P�\u0014a:\u0006�Y\u0011y�\f����`:\u0004¨>��*>\u0011冔H��V:�F�m\u0003,&.��Uǅ \u0011���u�\r\u0000)#����Pi�=\u001cOόR0�v@��Rd�$�oJ�\u0007RC�҈!#`Ӏ��o��X#\'I��[�w�\u001a�\u001e\u001f$���endstream\n' +
     'endobj\n' +
     '8 0 obj\n' +
     '<< /Filter /FlateDecode /Length1 19428 /Length 10359 >>\n' +
     'stream\n' +

Comment: When `result.data` retrieved by `responseType: 'arrayBuffer'` is used as `new Buffer.from(result.data)`, the attachment file can be opened without breaking. So in order to replicate your situation, can you provide the whole script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. By the way, your `fileId` is the file ID of Google Docs?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your reply. I'v updated the question with the complete code. The fileId is the ID of the Google Document, and I am not receiving any errors or empty responses. Any help or pointers in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue but I was able to successfully export the document in PDF and download it using Python with ```export_media(fileId=fileId,mimeType='application/pdf')```.I used the [following example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_google_document) (**check the node.js version**). My guess is that the problem is not when exporting but when sending the email attachemnt. **Could you let me know if you can get your file (not corrupted) before sending the email (i.e just export and download it locally instead) ?**

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. The exported PDF from Google Docs can be correctly opened at the email sent using nodemailer. So when I could correctly replicate your issue, I would like to think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Thanks for trying. I am also able to produce the PDF by extracting it as a stream, but not as an arrayBuffer. So, either I am doing something wrong with the arrayBuffer or something else fishy is going on. I know nodemailer also can handle streams, but I'm not quite sure how I can pipe the stream directly into nodemailer or how I should handle that case.

Comment: Hi ! Yes,I totally get you. Are you intending to exclusively use nodemailer or are you open to the possibility of using ```Gmail API``` or [Google's IMAP API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp)? Because combining Drive with Gmail API might come as an easier solution. Let me know if you would be ok with a solution of that kind. Thanks ! :D